# Spark-sql: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: apache-spark, hive

After quite some time, can't figure out how to identify root cause of below error when running spark-sql binary:

```
15/12/08 14:48:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory was not found.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1175)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$18.run(JDOHelper.java:2018)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$18.run(JDOHelper.java:2016)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.forName(JDOHelper.java:2015)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1162)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing datanucleus-api-jdo.jar in your class path. This jar is used by hive. Try to figure out which version of this jar you need (probably latest will do). You can download it then from here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/

And add it to hive permanently by adding this to your .hiverc file:

```
  add jar datanucleus-api-jdo.jar
```

Comment: Or if you are using HDP (Ambari), you can submit your Spark with: ``--jars "hdfs:///hdp/apps/2.4.0.0-169/hive/hive.tar.gz" ``

Comment: I'm getting this *error* when trying to provide *URL* of *local* `Hive MetaStore` in `hive.metastore.uris`. I've tried these URLs and none of them works: `thrift://localhost:10000`, `thrift://127.0.0.1:10000`, `jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000`; the first 2 URLs give me `metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...`, while last one gives this error

Answer (score 0):

For spark versions > 2.0, you can approach below solutions:

Make sure the `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` configuration which is pointing to complete path of metastore.

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL 

jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/hive/metastore_db;create=true
```

JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore

Place the `hive-site.xml` file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`to point SparkR to the same metastore as Hive Hope this solves your issue.